# tensorflow - multiply a vector of matrices against each matrix in another vector

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I had two tensors - **A** of shape `[4,3,3]` and **B** of shape `[2,3,3]`. For each `[3,3]` matrix in **A** I want to multiply with each `[3,3]` matrix in **B** to produce tensor **C** with shape `[4,2,3,3]`.

How can this be done in **Tensorflow**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.einsum('ikl,jkl->ijkl', A, B)`:

*Example:*

```
A = tf.reshape(tf.range(36), [4,3,3])
B = tf.reshape(tf.range(18), [2,3,3])
tf.einsum('ikl,jkl->ijkl', A, B)
# <tf.Tensor 'einsum/transpose_2:0' shape=(4, 2, 3, 3) dtype=int32>
```

Comment: Is there a similar way to do this with other arithmetic operators other than multiplication? Say I wanted to add A and B.

Comment: You can reshape `A` to (4,1,3,3) first, and then add A and B. `tf.reshape(A, [4,1,3,3]) + B`, which uses broadcasting property to do this.

Answer (score 0):

youcan unstack them for this op:

```
A = tf.reshape(tf.range(36), [4,3,3])
B = tf.reshape(tf.range(18), [2,3,3])
AB=[tf.matmul(i,j) for i in tf.unstack(A,int(A.shape[0]),0) for j in tf.unstack(B,int(B.shape[0]),0)]
AB=tf.reshape(tf.stack(output,0),[4,2,3,3])
```